# Batch processing in ImageMagick to create image masks from .mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, animation

I am creating animated sequences from video files. I am hoping to create image masks from the video files to save time on masking them by hand. [This tutorial](https://www.arj.no/2020/02/21/image-masks/) seems to clearly outline the process, however I have not been able to successfully input this command:

```
for i in *.tiff;
do
    name=`echo $i | cut -d'.' -f1';
    convert t01.tiff $i -compose difference -composite -threshold 5% -blur 0x3 \
          -threshold 20% -blur -0x3 "$name-mask.tiff" convert $i "name-mask.tiff" \
          -compose multiply -flatten "$name-clean.jpg"
done
```

When I enter this code, I receive:

```
>
```

I am using bash on Catalina and am a bit new to this workflow and command line in general.

Comment: Do you have two `convert` commands? Also, in your sample code you have `"name-mask.tiff"`, is the `$` missing? I would advice you use `${<varname>}` when using variables. It works everywhere and even if followed by a character which could be construed as a variable name character.

Comment: The problem is probably caused by line breaks when pasted in the terminal. Try creating a script instead. Read here: https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-create-and-use-bash-scripts/

Comment: @Matt This was the case! Followed the link, put the command in a script, worked as expected! Thank you!